# How to implement 'Adaptive Bit Rate' (HLS) with AVPlayer in iOS 9+

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am trying to implement adaptive bit rate with AVPlayer but i don't know how to switch between a low/high stream. I am a bit confused and have few questions:

1. Is it the sole responsibility of the server to implement HLS on its side  **OR**  the client also has to do something about it  **OR**  the client handles it automatically?
2. I am getting the following **URLs** from server, can someone tell me how to switch between the them based on network speed and what other steps are involved?

> {
>       "VideoStreamUrl": "http://50.7.149.74:1935/pitvlive/aplus3.stream/playlist.m3u8?",
>       "VideoStreamUrlLow": "http://50.7.149.74:1935/pitvlive/aplus3_240p.stream/playlist.m3u8?",
>       "VideoStreamUrlHD": null
>   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVPlayer supports HLS natively from the framework so you shouldnt need to do anything to support this.

The framework will automatically switch between low and high streams according to the current available bandwidth, so you dont actually need to pick a stream.

Comment: you mean server should not be sending me 3 URLs like the one above for 3 Streams, instead it should be sending only 1 URL to playlist.m3u8 AND in that playlist.m3u8 all 3 URLs should be embedded, Right???

Comment: exactly, and make sure the server is also serving the right mime type for the file extension